# No notification for comments posted on answers in my questions

Tags: feature-request

I recently opened one of my earlier asked question and I was surprised to see that there was a big discussion going on in the comments of one of the answers. But here I have not received any notification of these comments. It seems that if I have posted something, eg, a question or an answer and a comment is added on top of only the item posted by me then only I will get notified else I will not.

In my case since the question was asked by me and answer was posted by someone else so all the comments notifications added on the answer would be going only to the one who answered or the people tagged with @ symbol. But since I was the one who asked the question it was initially my doubt, and people discussing or telling good information in comments is something that just goes unnoticed by me because of the site feature.

I request to get this feature corrected such that the person who has asked the question gets notified for all the answers/comments that gets added/edited/deleted with his question/answers.

Comment: I think it will be more suitable in main meta

Comment: Waiting for the more replies to confirm that this happens with everyone and if this can be configured internally within the site. If not then can anyone please migrate it to main meta.

Comment: @Aby Yeah, it does happen to everyone, and it's not something that can be internally configured on Hinduism.SE.  So I suggest you post it on Meta.Stackedchange.  I think it would be really useful if you were notified when comments are posted on your answers.

Comment: Ok. I posted this question on main meta as well at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258378/no-notification-for-comments-posted-on-answers-in-my-questions